# REST File upload and validation / warnings

Tags: validation, rest

Which status code should be returned if I upload a file (or post a new resource) which is invalid but has been saved on the server anyway (that's a requirement here)?

Should I still return `201` and include a `FileValidationResult` in the response body?

Comment: should your client be able to do e.g. GET or DELETE the new resource? Or is the file just stored due to internal processing?

Comment: It's for internal processing or more specifically: one or more resources are created from it. The file contains product data and the service should create new products from the uploaded (XML) file and mark them as valid or invalid. If I would follow "REST principles" I could return all created products which contain there "IsValid" property. But that response might become huge and I also want to transfer the validation errors to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the upload from its processing.

After the POST you can reply with a `201` (or `202`, accepted) and the location of a collection resource (e.g. `/uploads/<upload_id>` which encapsulates the result of the upload. Through that resource you can then get e.g. created products and invalid products.

Also, this way, if processing takes longer, you can return quickly and have the collection resource return a status report if not yet finished.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds viable to me.